# Given the equation of a cylinder, find the parametric and locus form of the curve of intersection with plane

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, parametric, locus

Given the equation of a cylinder $x^2+z^2=1,$ describe the curve of intersection between the cylinder and the planes $z=x$ and $y=x$ in the parametric form and the form $F(x,y,z)=0$.

For $z=x$, I have the parametric equations $x=\cos t$, $y=y$ and $z=\cos t$ and then I substituted for $z$ in the equation of the cylinder. I don't know where to go from there.

For $y=x$, I know it's supposed to be an ellipse but I don't know how to write this in the form $F(x,y,z)=0.$ Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Hint: \begin{align} &\big\{(x,y,z)\,|\,g(x,y,z)=0\,\big\}\cap \big\{(x,y,z)\,|\,h(x,y,z)=0\,\big\}\\
=&\big\{(x,y,z)\,|\,g(x,y,z)^2+h(x,y,z)^2=0\,\big\}\end{align}